# Can't execute file via Server.Execute()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'd like to execute a file in a subsite.  Both the parent and sub site are web apps.  I don't want to redirect to the sub site file.  I'm trying to execute the sub file using Server.Execute() but it isn't working.

The main URL is:
http://mysite.com/subsite

Virtual path to file in subsite: ~/subsite/subfile.aspx

When I access http://mainsite.com/subsite/subfile.aspx, it works fine.  When I do

```
Server.Execute("~/subsite/subfile.aspx")
```

from the parent site, I get:

```
Could not load type 'Subsite.SubFile'.
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure server.execute doesn't cross application boundaries.  Could be wrong, but I don't think that will work.

Comment: You are probably right.  Is there another way?  If not, post your comment as the answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `server.execute` doesn't cross application boundaries.  I'm not 100% certain of that; but given the error message it seems likely.

Basically the error is saying that it can't locate (or load) the assembly that the `Subsite.SubFile` class is defined in.

I can think of two possible solutions.

1. Copy the assemblies for the Subsite into the main sites bin folder.  This *might* work because the main site could then locate the assembly and execute the code.  There are obvious drawbacks here.  Such as needing to have all of the config information from the subsite copied into the main sites web.config.  Also, any assemblies with the same name would be problematic; and, of course, needing to deploy the subsite on top of the main site every time there is an update...
2. Instead of doing a `server.execute`; use the `HttpRequest` class to make a regular http call to the sub site and then parse the response and write back to the browser what you need.